# Plasma directly to Solid or Liquid and vise versa

Tags: plasma-physics, gas, liquid-state

Let's forget how and go straight to the beef and potatoes. What do you scientifically call it when a plasma turns to liquid and skips recombination, and/or condensation? What about when a liquid turns to plasma and skips boiling, and ionization? What do you scientifically call it when a plasma turns to solid without going through recombination, condensation, and/or freezing? What would it be called if the previous question's process were reversed?

Answer (score 0):

A partial answer from comments by [honest_vivere](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/59023/honeste-vivere):

> I am not sure a plasma can go to a "solid" in the classical sense without recombination first, but maybe neutron stars or even white dwarfs could manage this in some places? As for the other way, the term for going directly from solid to a plasma is ablation and/or spallation with ionization. (One could, technically, ablate material to a gaseous form without ionizing it.)
>
> I do not know if a liquid-to-plasma phase transition is something people have studied or if it can be controlled in a lab setting to study. I have not heard of that type of phase transition, though that certainly does not mean it is not known or not studied.